# Managing references from the json_pack() function with the jansson library

Tags: c, json, parsing

I'm using `json_pack()` with the "o" specifiers like this:

```
json_pack("{s: o, s: o, s:o}", "foo", obj1, "foo2", obj2, "foo3", obj3);
```

I see in the [documentation](http://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apiref.html#building-values) for the "o" specifier:

> Output any given JSON value as-is. If the value is added to an array
>   or object, the reference to the value passed to o is stolen by the
>   container.

The thing that is blured for me is that if `json_pack()` fails, must I call `json_decref()` for my 3 objects (obj1, obj2 and obj3) or can I assume the `json_pack()` function did it for me, even in case of an error?

Comment: have you tried to test it?

Comment: seeing the difference between `O` and `o` you don't need to care about ref with `o`

Comment: @Ôrel: even in case of error? The jansson source code is a little hard for me to understand

Comment: Perhaps use `O` and manage the memory in your side will be easier.

Comment: Finally, I ended up using json_decref() on failure because it handles NULL values and 0-reference objects too so even if obj1/2/3 are freed on error, it is not a problem.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you're right! I could make the json_pack() fail and test the reference counters! thanks for this idea.